# a limit containing a digamma function

Tags: limits, digamma-function, polygamma

I wonder if the following limit is correct and how to prove it
$$
\lim _{x \rightarrow+\infty} \frac{4}{p^{2}} x^{4}\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}+\frac{2}{x}(\log 2+\Psi(x))+\Psi^{\prime}(x)\right)>0
$$
where $p>0$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I 've searched that $$
\Psi^{\prime}(x) \approx \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2 x^{2}}+\frac{1}{6 x^{3}}-\frac{1}{30 x^{5}}+\frac{1}{42 x^{7}}-\frac{1}{30 x^{9}}+\cdots
$$ when $x \rightarrow+\infty$. But I do not know how to process the $\Psi(x)$. I also do the experiment and the numerical result shows it seems to be true.

Comment: Maybe we can use this from wiki$$
\Psi(z) \approx \log z-\frac{1}{2 z}-\frac{1}{12 z^{2}}+\frac{1}{120 z^{4}}-\frac{1}{252 z^{6}}+\frac{1}{240 z^{8}}-\frac{5}{660 z^{10}}+\frac{691}{32760 z^{12}}-\frac{1}{12 z^{14}}+\cdots
$$ when $z \rightarrow+\infty$, and replace $\Psi(x)$ and $\Psi'(x)$ in the formulation, it may works?

Answer (score 0):

It is sufficient to use the asymptotic expansions you mentioned in the comments. From the asymptotic expansions it follows that as $x\to\infty$
$$
\frac{4}{p^{2}} x^{4}\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}+\frac{2}{x}(\log 2+\Psi(x))+\Psi^{\prime}(x)\right)\sim\frac{4}{p^2}x^3(1+\log 4+2\log x)+\mathcal O(x^2)\to\infty.
$$
And so for all $p>0$ the limit will diverge to $\infty$ and thus is greater than zero.